# Get Values from Database based on one textbox in a registration form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, webforms

I am making a basic web form with basic fields like name, email, number.
I just want, when i enter the number, rest of the fields are populated in the other textboxes based on that number from sql server. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Code is as follows :

```
    string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cmd = "IF NOT EXISTS(Select * from tbl_registration where Email = @Email OR MobileNo = @MobileNo) insert into tbl_registration values(@FirstName, @LastName,@Email,@MobileNo,@Address_1,@Address_2,@City,@State)";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfname.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtemail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", txtmob_no.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address_1", txtaddress1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address_2", txtaddress2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtcity.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtstate.Text);

                con.Open();
                int success = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (success > 0)
                {

                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Registration successfull')</script>");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Registration Not Sucessfull')</script>");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a basic exercise, what is great, keeps learning. A good practice is to isolate your front-end from your back-end. Read bout [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it will help you. Finally, you are merely writing data, in order to do what you want you also must read from the DB

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the method definition as shown below on the text box changed event.

This is not the complete query answer. Here is a [reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dataadapter-in-C-Sharp/) for you.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CSs))
    {
        string query = "Your SQL Query here";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "sometablename");
        firstnametext.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["sometablename"].Rows[0]["Firstname"]);
    }
```

Here you need to properly handle the null for the data table.

Comment: The change event fires on each keystroke and would not be appropriate for this requirement. Also, `ExecuteNonQuery` is much better than using a data adapter for inserts.

Comment: @Crowcoder Change event doesn't fire on each keystroke you need to check this and confirm. Key event only fire after value is changed and you lost focus from that text box.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking winforms, not webforms. Still, the data adapter is inappropriate here and adds no solution, just a different way.

Comment: @Crowcoder Can you check this answer remark - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234972/10532500?

Comment: Using data adapters to perform inserts is like carrying your car around on a flatbed truck instead of just driving the car itself. Even disregarding the blatant inefficiency of it, it does not provide a solution. OP is already on the right track, but has not yet stated what the actual issue is.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have given answer to get the data and display in the text box not to insert in the database on some text box change value. There is a contradiction between question heading and the question body. I have given answer as per the heading of the question.