# AccessViolationException with provider OraOLEDB.Oracle on 12C?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, access-violation, oraoledb

We were using Oracle 11g with MSDAORA as a provider but since MSDAORA will be deprecated we have to move to a new provider for the connection string. We're also using Oracle Client 12c right now

Before we were using: Provider=MSDAORA.1;Password=*****;User ID=*****;Data Source=****11G.WORLD; Persist Security Info=True

Now we're trying to use: Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;PLSQLRSet=true; Password=*****;User ID=******;Data Source=****11G.world;Persist Security Info=True

The problem is IIS crashes, and we got this exception, we have been trying to solve this issue for weeks and no luck yet:

Exception Details
**SystemAccessViolationException** Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

- **at** **System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.1CommandTextExecute**(IntPtr pUnkOuter, Guid& riid, tagDBPARAMS pDBParams, IntPtr& pcRowsAffected,
  Object& ppRowset)
- **at** **System.Data.01eDb.0IeDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult**(tagDBPAFtAMS
  dbParams, Object& executeResult)
- **at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText**(Object&
  executeResult)
- **at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand**(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
- **at System.Data.01eDb.01eDbCommand.ExecuteReaderIntemal**(CommandBehavior
  behavior, String method)
- **at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader**(CommandBehavior behavior)
- **at System.Data.01eDb.0IeDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader**(CommandBehavior
  behavior)
- **at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Filllnternal**(DataSet dataset, DataTable0 datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
  srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
- **at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill**(DataTableD dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command,
  CommandBehavior behavior)
- **at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill**(DataTable dataTable)
- **at M.Planned_DataloadDataCurGrid()** in D: Projects\ M\Planned_Data.aspx.vb:line 637
- **at M.Planned_Data.cmbProgram_SelectedIndexChanged**(Object sender, EventArgs e) in DAProjectAM \Planned_Data.aspx.vb:line
  484
- **at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged**(EventArgs
  e)
- **at System.Web.ULWebControls.DropDownListRaisePostDataChangedEvent()**
- at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownListSystem.Web.ULIPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvento
- at System.Web.ULPage.RaiseChangedEvents()

This is a simple minimum reproduction:

```vb
     Public Sub LoadGrid()
        Dim ocn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;PLSQLRSet=true; Password=*****;User ID=*****;Data Source=****11G.world;Persist Security Info=True")
        Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim odataSet As New DataTable

        Dim opm As OleDbParameter

        Dim oCmd As New OleDbCommand

        opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_language_code", OleDbType.Char)
        opm.Value = "E"
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(opm)

        opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_year_id", OleDbType.Integer)
        opm.Value = "2020"
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(opm)

        opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_month_id", OleDbType.Integer)
        opm.Value = "2"
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(opm)

        opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_program_id", OleDbType.Integer)
        opm.Value = "4"
        oCmd.Parameters.Add(opm)

        opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_location_id", OleDbType.Integer)

        opm.Value = "2"

        oCmd.Parameters.Add(opm)

        Try

            ocn.Open()
            oCmd.Connection = ocn
            oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            oCmd.CommandText = "***********"

            oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oda.SelectCommand = oCmd

            odataSet.Clear()
            oda.Fill(odataSet) 'This is where it crashes

          

            Dim rowcount As Integer = odataSet.Rows.Count

            dgCurrentYear.DataSource = odataSet
            dgCurrentYear.DataBind()

            If rowcount > 0 Then
                dgCurrentYear.Visible = True

            Else
                dgCurrentYear.Visible = False

            End If

        Catch ex As OleDbException
            ' Display the error


        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Display the error

        Finally
            ' Clean up
            If (Not ocn Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not ocn.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                ocn.Close()
            End If

            ocn = Nothing
            opm = Nothing

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Code like `opm = New OleDbParameter("pi_month_id", OleDbType.Integer)` `opm.Value = "2"` where the types don't match up makes me suspect that `Option Strict` is not being enforced. If Option Strict On has not been set as the default for the project then setting it on and correcting the problems it alerts you to could result in code that is more than three times faster.

Comment: Also, I suspect that the `ocn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;PLSQLRSet=true; Password=*****;User ID=*****;Data Source=****11G.world;Persist Security Info=True")
        Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter` should be inside a `Try`, or probably a `Using`. Code like `ocn = Nothing` is just *wrong* - the code should call `ocn.Dispose()`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It has not been my experience that Option Strict checks `DbType` to validate `.Value`. I wish it did. I always have it On.

Comment: @Mary That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

so we solved the problem by removing the line `oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Because I don't have to call ExecuteNonquery since the fill method of the DataAdapter is taking care of that.
[Programming Practice: Using ExecuteNonQuery with SqlDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234837/programming-practice-using-executenonquery-with-sqldataadapter/5234966)